# (Docker) executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a dockerfile but keep getting an error and I cant work it out for the life of me...

> docker run prometheus-vmware-exporter
> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "prometheus-vmware-exporter": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.15 as builder
WORKDIR /src/github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter
#WORKDIR /src/usr/bin/prometheus-vmware-exporter
COPY ./ /src/github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter
RUN go get -d -v
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build
FROM alpine:3.8
COPY --from=builder /src/github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter/prometheus-vmware-exporter /usr/bin/prometheus-vmware-exporter
#COPY --from=builder /src/github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter /home/gsquire/exporter/prometheus-vmware-exporter
EXPOSE 9512
ENTRYPOINT ["prometheus-vmware-exporter"]
```

---

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to reference the executable by its full path (`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/prometheus-vmware-exporter"]`)?

Comment: is the file executable? You can check that by running `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/ash <image-name-here>`. Within the container, run `ls -lisa /usr/bin | grep -i prometheus-vmware-exporter`.